# Elasticsearch need to find users having birthday in current week

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a newbie in Elasticsearch

I have a list of users in my index. I have birthdate key in my data which in unix timestamp.

Now i would like to find the users having upcoming birthday in this week! As we can find in MYSQL using Date and Month .

I have tried by set date format  : yyyy-MM-dd but still I am not able to get it

I have created a new key and in that added date format : dd-MM . that is worked for me using range condition!

I have tried as follows for dd-MM formate

```
GET /demo/_search
{
"query": {
    "range": {
       "birth_date_format": {
          "gte": "30-06",
          "lte": "30-06",
          "format": "dd-MM"
       }
    }
 }
}
```

But I would like to find the birth date by yyyy-MM-dd or timestamp so how can i do it? otherwise I can do it by dd-MM by adding new key

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

`now - 6d` = subtracting 6 days from today

`/w` = rounding to the nearest week

It is called [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) in elasticsearch.

```
{
     "_source":["birth_date_format"],
     "query": {
        "range": {
           "birth_date_format": {
             "gt": "now-6d/w",
             "lt":"now+6d/w"
           }
        }
     },
     "size":100
    
}
```

This will do the trick for you.

**Sample data:**

```
[
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-23"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-22"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-21"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-20"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-19"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-18"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-17"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-16"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-15"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-26"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-28"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-27"
            }
         },
         {

            "_source": {
               "birth_date_format": "2020-06-29"
            }
         }
      ]
```

**Output:**

```
"hits": [
            {
               
                "_source": {
                    "birth_date_format": "2020-06-23"
                }
            },
            {
               
                "_source": {
                    "birth_date_format": "2020-06-22"
                }
            },
            {
               
                "_source": {
                    "birth_date_format": "2020-06-26"
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "birth_date_format": "2020-06-28"
                }
            },
            {
               
                "_source": {
                    "birth_date_format": "2020-06-27"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Elasticsearch stores date as milliseconds - to calculate milliseconds it need year option.
2. (Built in date formats)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats] doesn't have a format without year.
3. Option1:

   1. You can index birthday as you have currently
   2. You need to index `birth Month` as another field
   3. You need to index `birth date` as another field
   4. You can use these two fields to query.
4. No way to do this with the help of [scripting](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-get-date-today/81264) also as we need to get current year to do calculations.

Comment: you said current week!! So you consider only month and date. Not the year? Why so?

Comment: I would like to find the birthday having users in current week!

Comment: Explain your `current week`. Why It should work for `1995-06-23`?

Comment: current_week means . i would like to find all the users birthday which are coming in this week! ex. the  users whose birthday is 1995-06-26 then it should come in my list! as i would like to send him greeting for his birthday

Comment: Got it!! I missed the `birthday` word :( I will update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216627/discussion-between-nitin-and-gibbs).

Comment: @Nitin check the answer and let me know please.

Comment: I have checked! as you mentioned early that i should follow the way which i have used! so we have continue in! and as per our suggestion you told me to use two different keys that will not suits for my problem as i would like to reduce number of keys in index!
so if i get the solution in single key then it will be great for me! and thanks for your support and your answers means a lot for me